# Function argument suddenly $null

Tags: powershell

This is the code with the function call:

```
$acl = Get-ACL -LiteralPath $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$explicitAces = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.isInherited -eq $false }
$result = AnalyzeGroups($path, $explicitAces)

function AnalyzeGroups([string]$path, $explicitAces) 
{
    # do something, return something
}
```

`$explicitAces` has AccessRules in form of an array. But as soon as I pass it as a argument and call the method `AnalyzeGroups` it becomes `$null`.

What's going on here?

Comment: You're only passing one argument at the moment. `AnalyzeGroups($path, $explicitAces)` --> `AnalyzeGroups $path $explicitAces`

Comment: I don't see it. EDIT: Okay thx!